# mysql - select most recent value with where

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have a table like below (lets called this table as t1)

```
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | timestamp           | p_value | TS                    | as_id | codename    |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 1  | 2019-03-13 07:55:44 | 561     | 2019-03-13 09:14:31   | 1795  | ActivePower |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 2  | 2019-03-13 07:55:44 | 561     | 2019-03-13 07:53:17   | 1795  | ActivePower |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 3  | 2019-03-13 07:55:45 | 561     | 2019-03-13 07:53:17   | 1795  | ActivePower |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 4  | 2019-03-13 07:55:48 | 974     | 2019-03-13 07:33:21   | 1795  | Cumulative  |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 5  | 2019-03-13 07:56:26 | 974     | 2019-03-13 07:33:28   | 1795  | Cumulative  |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to select the row with two conditions.

1. Get the row with the combination for `unique as_id, codename`

So, here my unique combination is

```
1795, ActivePower
1795, Cumulative
```

2. Filtered by the max timestamp value, if max timestamp is same, then order by id desc and limit by 1. So I can get the most recent row.

#### Expected output:

```
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | timestamp           | p_value | TS                    | as_id | codename    |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 3  | 2019-03-13 07:55:44 | 561     | 2019-03-13 07:53:17   | 1795  | ActivePower |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| 5  | 2019-03-13 07:56:26 | 974     | 2019-03-13 07:33:28   | 1795  | Cumulative  |
+----+---------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uses corelated subquery

```
  select t1.* from table_name t1
  where (t1.timestamp,id) in ( select max(timestamp),max(id) from 
                       table_name t2 where t1.as_id=t2.as_id
                       and t1.codename=t2.codename
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where id in 
    (select max(id) from tablename b where a.as_id=b.as_id and a.codename=b.codename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT  id, timestamp, p_value, TS, as_id, codename 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY as_id, codename ORDER BY TS DESC) AS RN
    FROM Table
) AS Q
WHERE RN = 1
```